# Compressing a Hex String in JavaScript/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, hex

My app generates links, which contain hex string like: `37c1fbcabbc31f2f8d2ad31ceb91cd8d0d189ca5963dc6d353188d3d5e75b8b3e401d4e74e9b3e02efbff0792cda5c4620cb3b1f84aeb47b8d2225cd40e761a5`. I would really like to make them shorter, like the solution mentioned for Ruby in [Compressing a hex string in Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993147/compressing-a-hex-string-in-ruby-rails).

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript/NodeJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node [int-encoder](https://github.com/alanclarke/int-encoder) does this, using the strategy already mentioned.

it also supports large numbers

```
npm install int-encoder

var en = require('int-encoder');

//simple integer conversion
en.encode(12345678); // "ZXP0"
en.decode('ZXP0'); // 12345678

//convert big hex number using optional base argument
en.encode('e6c6b53d3c8160b22dad35a0f705ec09', 16); // 'hbDcW9aE89tzLYjDgyzajJ'
en.decode('hbDcW9aE89tzLYjDgyzajJ', 16); // 'e6c6b53d3c8160b22dad35a0f705ec09'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method, that basically are doing the same thing of the methods you mentioned in the link:

```
var hexString = "4b3fc1400";
var b36 = parseInt(hexString, 16).toString(36); // "9a29mgw"
```

And to convert it back, you just need to do the opposite:

```
hexString = parseInt(b36, 36).toString(16); // "4b3fc1400"
```

The only problem with your string, is that is too big to be threat as number in JavaScript. You should split them in chunk. JavaScript's numbers are accurate up to 2^53 (plus sign), so the max positive number you can handle is 0x20000000000000 (in hexadecimal, that is 9007199254740992 in decimal); you can use the accuracy to handle the chunk:

```
var hexString = "37c1fbcabbc31f2f8d2ad31ceb91cd8d0d189ca5963dc6d353188d3d5e75b8b3e401d4e74e9b3e02efbff0792cda5c4620cb3b1f84aeb47b8d2225cd40e761a5"

var b36 = "", b16 = "";

var chunk, intChunk;

// 14 is the length of 0x20000000000000 (2^53 in base 16)

for (var i = 0, max = 14; i < hexString.length; i += max) {
    chunk = hexString.substr(i, max);
    intChunk = parseInt(chunk, 16);

    if (intChunk.toString(16) !== chunk) {
        intChunk = parseInt(hexString.substr(i, max - 1), 16);
        i -= 1;
    }

    b36 += intChunk.toString(36)
}

// 11 is the length of 2gosa7pa2gv (2^53 in base 36)

for (var i = 0, max = 11; i < b36.length; i += max ) {
    chunk = b36.substr(i, max);
    intChunk = parseInt(chunk, 36);

    if (intChunk.toString(36) !== chunk) {
        intChunk = parseInt(b36.substr(i, max - 1), 36);
        i -= 1;
    }

    b16 += intChunk.toString(16)
}

console.log(hexString);
console.log(b36);
console.log(b16);
```

**Update:** You could also use a base 62 instead of 36 to compress more, but notice that JS supports up to base 36, so you need to implement that [personal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) manually (I believe there are already some implementation around).

Comment: how can i convert from string to base36, need it for trying to learn api of reddit where full name is something t2_36basesencodedHere http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#fullnames

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and fastest thing to do is define a set of 64 safe characters for use in the URL, such as A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, and $.  Then encode every three hex digits (4 bits each) into two safe characters (6 bits each).  This requires no multiplication and division, and it can be used on arbitrarily long strings.

You will need to pick a 65th character to use at the end of the string to indicate if the last four-bit piece is used or not.  Otherwise you will have an ambiguity for character strings with an even number of characters.  Let's call it *2n*.  Then there are either *3n-1* or *3n* hex digits encoded within, but there is no way to tell which.  You can follow the sequence with a special character to indicate one of those cases.  E.g. a '.' (period).

Note: The last few characters picked here for the set differ from Base64 encoding, since URLs have their own definition of safe punctuation characters.  See [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).